# Google Sheets Formula for UPPER and PROPER text

Tags: regex, google-sheets

Sample file [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1K86FCnrvkZEk6lRHP6M_JSHIevWhMeqNku2TyGA6-hw/edit#gid=979671405).

I need a formula that will convert space separated text such that the text is in PROPER case except where the word is in UPPER case which is left as is.

So the following formula works - for one cell.

```
=ArrayFormula(JOIN(" ",IF(EXACT(SPLIT(A1," ",TRUE,TRUE),UPPER(SPLIT(A1," ",TRUE,TRUE))),UPPER(SPLIT(A1," ",TRUE,TRUE)),PROPER(SPLIT(A1," ",TRUE,TRUE)))))
```

But I want to convert a whole range at one go - ArrayFormula type.

Possible? Using another method even.

EDIT;

'a BIG BAd   wOLF OF yonder' -> 'A BIG Bad Wolf OF Yonder'

Comment: @I'-'I If the word is in UPPER case, keep the word in UPPER case (as is). I have edited the OP with an example of expected output.

Comment: @pnuts Is there an click/option to view such 'pending' actions? Also, I'm a relative new user, so am not very familiar with such expectations.

Comment: @pnuts Member yes, but rarely active. Perhaps, this last few weeks has been the most active that I've been.

Comment: It is not possible with a mere RE2 regexp, you need a custom function. [Regex is powerful](https://regex101.com/r/14LL1Y/1), but not every flavor supports all regex features like regex101.com.